# uploading data into Big Query

Tags: google-cloud-platform

is there a way to unzip a file that has been loaded into Google Cloud Platform.

I have a 33GB Zip File filled with CSV files enroute to Google Big Query.

If Unzipped, the file size is over 215GB.

Is there a way to load the Zip File and uncompress it in GCP instead of trying to upload 215GB of raw data?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using gzip compression? According to [this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/preparing-data-for-loading#loading_compressed_and_uncompressed_data) BigQuery should be able to take in gzipped file (might be useful to read the side notes though).

Answer (score 0):

If it's gzipped then you can load into BigQuery from Google Cloud Storage. Otherwise, I don't believe there is a way to unzip once it's in GCS.

One option is to spin up a Google Compute Engine with enough hard drive space (and preferably SSDs), do whatever you want there and then push to GCS from there then shut down the Compute Engine